# Loop through only once SlideJS

Tags: jquery, slider

I'm using [SlidesJS](http://www.slidesjs.com/) which is pretty straightforward, but there's currently not option to autostart but only play through once and stop. It currently loops.

I need it to play through once, then stop at the first slide again.

There's an animationComplete function, however, so I'm thinking I could use this to test when the full animation is complete, it checks the length (number of slides) and if it's greater than the number, then it stops the slider.

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/55Evw/**

This is what I have so far:

```
$(function(){
    $('.slides').slides({
        play: 5000,
        slideSpeed: 1000,
        bigTarget: true,
        generatePagination: false,
        hoverPause: true,
        animationComplete: function(current) { 
            var total = $(".slides_container div").length; 
            if (current >= total) {                 
                clearInterval($('.slides').data('interval')); 
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And the basics of my HTML structure:

```
   <div class="slides">
        <div class="slides_container">
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
            </div>
            <div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/570x270">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Cheers,
R

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle?

Comment: Thanks. Played around with it, but it didn't make much sense to me I'm afraid. :( If I was you though I'd build the slideshow from scratch, it's really not that hard. That way you'll have full control of everything.